# Is object's property be garbage collected with object in C#, or they have separate gc mechanism

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I'm just thinking about a question that if there's a class like:

```
public class A 
{
    public CustomType PropertyA { get; set; }
    public CustomType PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

and I create an instance of it:

```
var a = new A 
{
    PropertyA = SomeValue,
    PropertyB = SomeOtherValue
};
```

then I set `PropertyA` to null like `a.PropertyA = null;` will the `PropertyA`'s value be garbage collected, or it won't be collected until object `a` be collected?

Comment: If it's an object on the heap with no references to it, I would expect it to be garbage collected.  The fact that one or more previous references was a property on another object shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: You have an object being referenced by `SomeValue`. Then you make a copy of this reference into `a.PropertyA`. Then you remove that last reference by assigning `null` to this property. If you still have `SomeValue`, and this variable is still in use, the object will be ineligible for collection. Once no rooted references (in)directly reference the object, it is eligible for collection. So this depends on the lifetime of the `SomeValue` variable (or whatever that thing is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through this example, we can say that GC works separately for any property instance of an object.

```
using System;

public class Dog
{
    public Dog(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public string Name;
    public Breed Breed;
}

public class Breed
{
    public Breed(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dog dog = new Dog("Bowser");
        dog.Breed = new Breed("Pug");
        WeakReference dogRef = new WeakReference(dog);
        WeakReference breedRef = new WeakReference(dog.Breed);
        Console.WriteLine(dogRef.IsAlive);
        Console.WriteLine(breedRef.IsAlive);

        dog.Breed = null;
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine(breedRef.IsAlive);

        dog = null;
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine(dogRef.IsAlive);
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
true
true
false
false
```